# Is it reasonable to apply different offsets to different species in community analysis?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, negative-binomial-distribution, ecology, offset

I am using the `manyglm` function from the mvabund package. I have a site X species/family dataset of counts. One organism in the community is vastly more abundant than the others (by multiple orders of magnitude) so a standard practice for sampling is to use one effort to get a count for that organism. The rest of the community is sampled under a separate, larger effort. Is it possible to apply different offsets to different species? Is it ok to assume a singular community at each site when we used different efforts for different species?

Further clarification if needed: These are zooplankton samples. We go to a site, collect site variables, collect a volume of water. That water is filtered for the abundant organisms - rotifers. A second portion of water, much more, is filtered for the less abundant organisms - crustaceans. Ultimately, we get individuals/Liter for each family or species but the multiplier is different. These data tend to best fit a negative-binomial distribution.

Comment: I can see no problems in using different offsets